# Infinispan life span is not working

Tags: infinispan

```
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">

            <local-cache name="entity">

                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>

                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>

                <expiration max-idle="10000" lifespan="10000"/>

            </local-cache>

            <local-cache name="local-query">

                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>

                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>

                <expiration max-idle="10000" lifespan="10000"/>

            </local-cache>
```

this is my configuration, i have set lifespan 10000 but after 100 sec cache is not expired
there is any error in my configuration

Comment: No, your configuration looks fine. Could you also share your code (test-case, ideally), inserting those entries into cache and then retrieving them?

Comment: As well as the suggestions by Flavius, these caches are specifically used by Hibernate 2LC use case. Adding lifespan to these caches is counter productive really.